# Facing this issue after add Spatialite in my project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode6, xcode7

New Help Dose any one face this issue?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Project Settings -> Under "Targets", select your project ->build phases-> open "Compile Sources" and "Copy Bundle Resources". Check if any files are listed in red color. If so,just delete it.Then clean and run.

Comment: No listed in red color. :(